# How to get the current spdlog level?

Tags: c++, logging, log-level, spdlog

I need to turn off the spdlog level before some code then return it to the previous value after.

How do I get the current level before turning it off?

Comment: Hello Howaida... please consider accepting an answer to this question.

Answer (score 6):

#### Scenario 1: User-constructed logger

If you have a `spdlog::logger` object you're using (say, `my_logger`), then:

- You can obtain the level with: `my_logger.level()`.
- If you just want to know whether a certain-level message would be logged, then use `my_logger.should_log(some_level)` where `some_level` could be, for example `spdlog::level::debug`.

#### Scenario 2: The global logger

Now suppose you're using the global logger (e.g. you emit log messages using  `spdlog::info()`, `spdlog::error()` and such).

**`spdlog` version 1.8.0 and later**

You can obtain the global log level with a call to `spdlog::get_level()` (which is a freestanding function, not a method).

**`spdlog` versions before 1.8.0**

You need to get your hand on the implicit logger object - by calling`spdlog::default_logger_raw()` (it gets you a pointer.) Now just proceed as in Scenario 1 above.

Answer (score 4):

To get current level of logger use [logger::level()](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/032035e72f73b232e2fa087dc6021a3732c9f6ae/include/spdlog/logger.h#L111).

To set new level use [logger::set_level()](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/032035e72f73b232e2fa087dc6021a3732c9f6ae/include/spdlog/logger.h#L110).

Answer (score 2):

There seems now to be a function to get the global logging level:

```
spdlog::get_level();
```

Comment: spdlog::get_level() was added in [v1.8.0](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/blob/4a9ccf7e38e257feecce0c579a782741254eaeef/include/spdlog/spdlog-inl.h#L50).

Comment: I took the liberty of integrating your answer and @Corey's comment into my answer; but +1.

Comment: @einpoklum feel free :)